# Allow CSS Grid to grow vertically with window, filling remaining space

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to grow a grid to fill the remaining vertical space. There are a couple `div`s above a calendar of fixed height, and I'd like those to remain a fixed height. As the window grows vertically, I'd like only the calendar to change, with each row growing evenly, stopping at the bottom of the window with no scrollbars.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

html,
body {
  background: #92bde7;
  color: #485e74;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}

.selection {
  padding: 5px;
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
}

.header>div {
  padding: 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


/* this is the element that needs to stretch to remaining available window space */

.calendar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
}


/* these elements should stretch evenly as the window grows */

.calendar>div {
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 0.5em;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.prev>div,
.next>div,
.date>div {
  text-align: left;
}

.prev,
.next {
  background: #c9e6ff;
  color: #666;
}

.date {
  background: #f9feff;
}
```

```html
<div class="selection">
  <h1><a class="back">&#10094;</a> 6 / 2018 <a class="forward">&#10095;</a></h1>
</div>
<div class="header">
  <div>Sunday</div>
  <div>Monday</div>
  <div>Tuesday</div>
  <div>Wednesday</div>
  <div>Thursday</div>
  <div>Friday</div>
  <div>Saturday</div>
</div>
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="prev">30</div>
  <div class="prev">31</div>
  <div class="date">1
    <div class="item">Stuff to do...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="date">2</div>
  <div class="date">3</div>
  <div class="date">4</div>
  <div class="date">5</div>

  <div class="date">6</div>
  <div class="date">7</div>
  <div class="date">8</div>
  <div class="date">9</div>
  <div class="date">10</div>
  <div class="date">11</div>
  <div class="date">12</div>

  <div class="date">13</div>
  <div class="date">14</div>
  <div class="date">15</div>
  <div class="date">16</div>
  <div class="date">17</div>
  <div class="date">18</div>
  <div class="date">19</div>

  <div class="date">20</div>
  <div class="date">21</div>
  <div class="date">22</div>
  <div class="date">23</div>
  <div class="date">24</div>
  <div class="date">25</div>
  <div class="date">26</div>

  <div class="date">27</div>
  <div class="date">28</div>
  <div class="date">29</div>
  <div class="date">30</div>
  <div class="next">1</div>
  <div class="next">2</div>
  <div class="next">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like it works to me in FF, but I may not understand.

Comment: @johnny the calendar grid doesn't grow as the window is stretched.  stretching is the desired behavior.  in Chrome, it's just static vertically.  Horizontally, it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Try wrapping the whole thing a in a flex container, then using flex properties to set your lengths. Something like this:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
    
.selection {
  flex: 0 0 50px; /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
}
   
.header {
  flex: 0 0 25px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
}
    
.calendar {
  flex: 1; /* dynamic length; consumes all remaining space */
  overflow: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/24no0wzo/)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to accomplish this. One way to do this is to leverage `vh` units. I [made a CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PerVwQ) with your code and made a slight tweak to the height of your rows in CSS:

```
.calendar > div {
    ...
    height: calc(20vh - 17px)
}
```

This means that each row will take up 20% of the vertical space of the screen minus 17px, which allows for the header. This assumes there will always be five rows.

Comment: The downside of five rows means it will fail when February starts on Sunday and has 28 days. Of course, that will only happen three times in the next 35 years.